# Display Disk Size and FreeSpace in GB

Tags: powershell

Is there one line of code that will display free-size and disk-space of your logical disk in gb instead of mb? I tried doing some research but I couldn't find one liner, I did give this an attempt which was to divide it by 1GB, but that didn't work, how can I accomplish this?

```
gwmi win32_logicaldisk | Format-Table DeviceId, MediaType,Size,FreeSpace /1GB
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try calculated properties. I would also add `[math]::Round()` to shorten the values:

```
gwmi win32_logicaldisk | Format-Table DeviceId, MediaType, @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="FreeSpace";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}
```

`n` stands for `name` and `e` for `expression`. You could use the full names too, but it's a waste of space if you're writing multiple calculated Properties.

Comment: what is the 2 doing to the script?

Comment: Number of decimals

Comment: If someone really finds it necessary to downvote, I would appreciate a comment to explain why it was bad. He asks for a one-liner to show values in GB, which I provided and it works.... :S

Comment: This always happens, users downvote without a reason or maybe there's a reason but never tell, what can you do..

Comment: @Francesc I was marking it as 'answered' but checked the downvote. Please edit the answer so I can upvote (it won't let me remove the downvote without you making an edit). Purely my bad.

Comment: @PirateX what? You undo downvote by clicking on the downvote Arrow to unselect it. No need for edit. Don't really understand how you were going to make it "answered" to since this is francesc's answer.

Comment: Mate, please understand that I do not make the rules for SO. `You last voted on this answer 3 hours ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited`

Comment: Upvoted :) . I am not sure either why I got this error.

Comment: @FrodeF I have a question you may be able to answer. I am using something similar to what you have posted, but if I only wanted the integer result of freespace to be returned because it was going to be stored in a variable as an input into another command, what would you recommend I do?

Comment: didn't know you could shorten to `n` & `e` +1

Answer (score 10):

I'd like to provide an alternate/updated answer. (As of Powershell 5 at least, probably version 3.)

Just use `Get-Volume`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-volume

Example:

```
> get-volume
    
DriveLetter FriendlyName     FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatus SizeRemaining     Size
----------- ------------     -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------- -------------     ----
                             FAT32          Fixed     Healthy      OK                       451 MB   496 MB
C           OSDISK           NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     65.23 GB 474.3 GB
X           Transfer_Shuttle NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK                     37.65 GB 48.68 GB
```

Comment: Hey it only took until 2020 to get something reasonably close to df -ah!

Comment: :P To be fair, it looks like get-volume has been around since Server2012/Powershell 3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-volume?view=winserver2012-ps

Answer (score 9):

When performing any arithmetical calculation, it should be put in `{ }`.

```
gwmi win32_logicaldisk | Format-Table DeviceId, MediaType,Size, {$_.FreeSpace /1GB}
```

You can read more on syntax from [Microsoft Powershell Library](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692684.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue and I want get KB,MB,GB,TB,PB on Server with Windows Server 2008 to 2016,
then I google many information to build a function:

```
function ConvertDoubleToBytes([double]$srcDouble){
    if([Math]::Floor([Math]::Log($srcDouble,1024)) -eq 0){
        $resn = ([Math]::Ceiling($srcDouble/([math]::pow(1024,([Math]::Floor([Math]::Log($srcDouble,1024)))))).ToString() + " Bytes")
    } elseif ([Math]::Floor([Math]::Log($srcDouble,1024)) -eq 1){
        $resn = ([Math]::Ceiling($srcDouble/([math]::pow(1024,([Math]::Floor([Math]::Log($srcDouble,1024)))))).ToString() + " KB")
    } elseif ([Math]::Floor([Math]::Log($srcDouble,1024)) -eq 2){
        $resn = ([Math]::Ceiling($srcDouble/([math]::pow(1024,([Math]::Floor([Math]::Log($srcDouble,1024)))))).ToString() + " MB")
    } elseif ([Math]::Floor([Math]::Log($srcDouble,1024)) -eq 3){
        $resn = ([Math]::Ceiling($srcDouble/([math]::pow(1024,([Math]::Floor([Math]::Log($srcDouble,1024)))))).ToString() + " GB")
    } elseif ([Math]::Floor([Math]::Log($srcDouble,1024)) -eq 4){
        $resn = ([Math]::Ceiling($srcDouble/([math]::pow(1024,([Math]::Floor([Math]::Log($srcDouble,1024)))))).ToString() + " TB")
    } elseif ([Math]::Floor([Math]::Log($srcDouble,1024)) -eq 5){
        $resn = ([Math]::Ceiling($srcDouble/([math]::pow(1024,([Math]::Floor([Math]::Log($srcDouble,1024)))))).ToString() + " PB")
    }
    return $resn
}
```

And I use it:

```
Get-WmiObject -query "Select * from win32_logicaldisk " | Select-Object DeviceID,@{n="FreeSpace";e={ConvertDoubleToBytes($([double]::Parse($_.FreeSpace)))}},@{n="Size";e={ConvertDoubleToBytes($([double]::Parse($_.Size)))}},@{n="Useage Percent";e={$([Math]::Ceiling((1-$($([double]::Parse($_.FreeSpace))/$([double]::Parse($_.Size))))*100)).ToString() + " %"}}
```

Will print like this:

```
DeviceID FreeSpace Size   Useage Percent
-------- --------- ----   --------------
C:       36 GB     100 GB 65 %
D:       294 GB    600 GB 52 %
E:
F:       279 GB    600 GB 54 %
G:
H:       500 GB    500 GB 1 %
```

Answer (score 1):

This works great.

$disks = get-wmiobject Win32_LogicalDisk -computername $computer -Filter "DriveType = 3"

foreach ($disk in $disks) {

```
$letter = $disk.deviceID
$volumename = $disk.volumename
$totalspace = [math]::round($disk.size / 1GB, 2)
$freespace = [math]::round($disk.freespace / 1GB, 2)
$usedspace = [math]::round(($disk.size - $disk.freespace) / 1GB, 2)
$disk | Select-Object @{n = "Computer Name"; e = { $computer } }, @{n = "Disk Letter"; e = { $letter } }, @{n = "Volume Name"; e = { $volumename } }, @{n = "Total Space"; e = { ($totalspace).tostring() + " GB" } }, @{n = "Free Space"; e = { ($freespace).tostring() + " GB" } }, @{n = "Used Space"; e = { ($usedspace).tostring() + " GB" } } | FT
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).