# Why does start-job cancel previous job when starting the same exe?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1, start-job

I want to execute same *exe* with different, parallel arguments each time in a loop.

So I decided to use `Start-Job`, but when I try it, I realize that when the second instance starts, the first is cancelled:

```
foreach($name in $insanceNames)
{
   Start-Job -ScriptBlock { & "C:\program.exe" $args } -ArgumentList /instName,$name
}
```

When second instance is started, the first one is interrupted with no errors.

If I execute the same program, in parallel, through two consoles manually, I don't have this problem.

NOTE: I cannot start program just with "&" because I need to run them without waiting previous instance finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I changed `Start-Job` for `Start-Process` and it works as I expected.

I was looking for the difference between both in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60270146/2098871) and i don't understand why `Start-Job` stops previous instance and `Start-Process` keep all the intance as expected.

However, I solved my problem.